# How to increment value on progress-bar?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a progress bar which is supposed to be filled up from 0% to 100% withing 3 seconds by a click.

[Codepen example](http://codepen.io/Alexnotonfire/pen/AXRXpm)

```
<progress class="progress is-large is-info" max="100" value="10"></progress>
</br>
<button onclick="move()">Click Me</button>
```

Since there is no **document.getElementByValue** how could I increment **value** attribute in a loop to get it done?

Comment: Add the attribute `id` to your progress bar and access the element by `documnet.getElementById`.

Comment: Hi please see the link: http://jsfiddle.net/DgXM6/3/

Comment: You can use `querySelector` though, but this would get all elements with same value: `document.querySelector("progress[value='10']");`

Comment: @Arg0n: `document.querySelector()` returns either one node (the first node matching the selector, if any) or `null`; it doesn't "*get all elements...*" you're thinking of, I assume, `document.querySelectorAll()`.

Comment: Is there a reason you need the progress element and a solution that iterates via JS and somehow uses the value, or would a purely visual solution based on CSS be acceptable as well? (I suppose so, as going from 0 to 100 doesn't sound like it has functionality behind it except the visual part)

Comment: You can just get a reference to the progress bar with `document.getElementsByClassName("progress")[0]`, and it's value with `.value`. I'd suggest to assign an ID to the element, so you can get a reference to is with `getElementById` instead.

Comment: @DavidThomas I see, I usually use jQuery, so not that familiar with it tbh. I thought it worked in a similar way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding an `id` to the progressbar allows to use `document.getElementById`. After that all that needs to happen is set an interval and increment `progress.value`. Ids are ideal for this situation as they are unique identifiers for a specific element on the page.

http://codepen.io/chasenyc/pen/grWrKR

```
function move() {
  var progress = document.getElementById("progressbar");
  var width = 1;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 10);

  function frame() {
    if (width >= 100) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      width++;
      progress.value = width
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Add the attribute `id` to your progress bar and access the element by `document.getElementById`. Also added the loop to show the progress.

[Updated CodePen.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wWdWxp)

**Check the example below:**

```js
var progress = document.getElementById("progressbar");

function move() {
  var a = setInterval(function() {
    progress.value = progress.value + 1;

    if (progress.value == 100) {
      clearInterval(a);
    }
  }, 25);
}
```

```css
.progress.is-large {
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<progress id="progressbar" class="progress is-large is-info" max="100" value="10"></progress>
</br>
<button onclick="move()">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an approach that is different from your original attempt, however has a few advantages compared to looping +1s:

- JS is only used to trigger the animation, however animating is entirely handled by the browser - this results in a very smooth animation while needing much less processing power (though that last point is likely irrelevant for most devices, I still prefer it this way)
- it requires almost no code and incorporates style-ability, which you likely want anyway
- it scales to the width property of it's parent in a very flexible manner.
- if you're not looking for a linear progression, you can easily use a different [timing function](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-timing-function.asp) by exchanging a single word

The downside is that it requires CSS3.

```css
#progress-bar-container {
  background-color: #ddd;
  width: 300px;
}
#progress-bar {
  background-color: #08f;
  height: 20px;
  transition: width 3s linear;
  width: 0%;
}
#progress-bar.full {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="progress-bar-container">
  <div id="progress-bar"></div>
</div>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('progress-bar').className += ' full'">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: It would be ideal to be able to vary the transition time programmatically.  How do I change the transition time in code?  I am guessing something like: document.getElementById("progress-bar").style.transitionDuration = "1s";

Comment: This progress bar is not reusable... any suggestions?

Comment: @pollaris: Reuseable as in empty again, then fill up again? It's outside the scope of the question, so I won't edit the answer, but basically you have to use a conditional statement/if-clause within the `onclick` attribute.

Comment: I found I can reset the bar with document.getElementById("progress-bar").style.width = "0%"; (and then start it up again with document.getElementById("progress-bar").style.width = "100%";) making it reusable. I can reset the timer with document.getElementById("progress-bar").style.transitionDuration = SIZE;  I like this style a lot.

Comment: @pollaris: Ah, I figured you meant using the same button, using the button only as a placeholder trigger, assuming OP intended to use something else as the trigger mechanism, as a progress bar by itself isn't mightily useful. :) Good luck on your endeavours, and if you have more exhaustive questions about this, please post a new question.