# How to change color of a progress bar (JS or CSS)

Tags: javascript, html, css, progress-bar, background-color

I saw a perfect topic here : [How to increment value on progress-bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38123404/how-to-increment-value-on-progress-bar?rq=1)

I would like to insert a progress bar like that in my web project.

So i follow [this codepen](https://codepen.io/chasenyc/pen/grWrKR).

```js
function move() {
  var progress = document.getElementById("progressbar");
  var width = 1;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 10);

  function frame() {
    if (width >= 100) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      width++;
      progress.value = width
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.progress.is-large {
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<progress id="progressbar" class="progress is-large is-info" max="100" value="1"></progress>
</br>
<button onclick="move()">Click Me</button>
```

I have juste one problem, i don't know how to change the color of the progress bar before animation and after animation.

Comment: You should make those links clickable, and also pull in some of the code from the codepen so that others can view it here. That will make it easier for others to answer your question

Comment: Are you using Jquery?

Answer (score 1):

Are are various pseudo-classes that can be changed, but this is browser specific. See the following demo. Note that the background of the progress element itself has to be set for the changes to the bar to apply, at least in Chrome. Not entirely sure why.

```js
function move() {
  var progress = document.getElementById("progressbar");
  var width = 1;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 10);

  function frame() {
    if (width >= 100) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      width++;
      progress.value = width
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.progress {
  height: 40px;
  background: black;
}
.progress::-moz-progress-bar
{
    background: red;
}
.progress::-webkit-progress-bar
{
    background: transparent;
}
.progress::-webkit-progress-value
{
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<progress id="progressbar" class="progress is-large is-info" max="100" value="1"></progress>
</br>
<button onclick="move()">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [`accent-color`](https://caniuse.com/?search=accent-color) property for form controls.

```js
function move() {
  var progress = document.getElementById("progressbar");
  var width = 1;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
  document.getElementById("myBtn").disabled = true;

  function frame() {
    if (width >= 100) {
      clearInterval(id);
      document.getElementById("myBtn").disabled = false;
    } else {
      width++;
      progress.value = width
    }
  }
}
```

```css
progress {
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  accent-color: #ff9800;
}
```

```html
<progress id="progressbar" max="100" value="1"></progress>
<button onclick="move()" id="myBtn">Click Me</button>
```

---

Alternatively, you can achieve `accent-color` changes dynamically through JavaScript.

```
document.getElementById("progressbar").style.accentColor = "#ff9800";
```